# How to align the title and the author left this way?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, titles

I have to do a Word exam, but i don't want to use word, so i thought i will "learn" latex by doing this exam with it.

The first problem was with the firs page, neither of the solutions i had tested worked as it supposed to.

Here is the example i have to make. [image]

Sorry for the unreadable text, i think you dont have to be able to understand the text to understand my problem.

I managed to do the table of content with this:

```
%% Table of content
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
```

But i cant do the title and the author part.

Comment: +1 for trying to learn LaTeX and getting rid oft Word. **But** if your exercise is simply to copy the layout of a few random pages as similar as possible, you may indeed better use a word processor like Word or LibreOffice. The learning curve in Latex is rather steep if you try to copy different formatting aspects en detail